# PHP copy mysql schema and data

Tags: php, mysql, schema, data-migration

I am using a small script to automate schema transfers between servers, but now I will need to modify it to also include data. I am not that good with PHP so I am asking for your help.
This is what I have so far (parts I got from another source, not mine):

`/*********** GRAB OLD SCHEMA ***********/
    $db1 = mysql_connect($DB_SRC_HOST,$DB_SRC_USER,$DB_SRC_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($DB_SRC_NAME, $db1) or die(mysql_error());`

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES;",$db1) or die(mysql_error());
$buf="set foreign_key_checks = 0;\n";
$constraints='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $result2 = mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE ".$row[0].";",$db1) or die(mysql_error());
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        if(preg_match("/[ ]*CONSTRAINT[ ]+.*\n/",$res[1],$matches))
        {
                $res[1] = preg_replace("/,\n[ ]*CONSTRAINT[ ]+.*\n/","\n",$res[1]);
                $constraints.="ALTER TABLE ".$row[0]." ADD ".trim($matches[0]).";\n";
        }
        $buf.=$res[1].";\n";
}
$buf.=$constraints;
$buf.="set foreign_key_checks = 1";

/**************** CREATE NEW DB WITH OLD SCHEMA ****************/
$db2 = mysql_connect($DB_DST_HOST,$DB_DST_USER,$DB_DST_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE '.$DB_DST_NAME;
if(!mysql_query($sql, $db2)) die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DB_DST_NAME, $db2) or die(mysql_error());
$queries = explode(';',$buf);
foreach($queries as $query)
        if(!mysql_query($query, $db2)) die(mysql_error());
```

How can I modify the existing code to include data as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transfer both the data /and/ the schema, why not do a mysqldump, and just read the whole thing back in? What does this not to, that the script is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I am just trying to speed things up. This script basically grabs all tables and recreates them to the target database (which it also creates)

Comment: Why would this be any quicker then just using MySQL's own dump/read function? I do this all the time, and just use: mysqldump > file.sql and then mysql < file.sql. Works like a charm... :)

Comment: That's what I normally use as well, but this is to be used by people without basic knowledge of MySQL as well. So I have been trying to make them a script that will take care of all basic moving tasks...

Comment: Ah, i see. What about this? [link](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/web_space__access/mysql/13.html)

Comment: I read this, but it relied on exec and a two-part proccess. I found a way to do it directly, without exec. It's dirty and will probably not work that well on large databases, but it's a start...see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

After going though a lot of links and tutorials, I managed to come up with something that simply works! Here is the code:

```
$connectDST = mysql_connect($DB_DST_HOST, $DB_DST_USER, $DB_DST_PASS);
mysql_select_db($DB_DST_NAME, $connectDST);
set_time_limit(0);

$connectSRC = mysql_connect($DB_SRC_HOST, $DB_SRC_USER, $DB_SRC_PASS);

mysql_select_db($DB_SRC_NAME, $connectSRC);

$tables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $DB_SRC_NAME");

while ($line = mysql_fetch_row($tables)) {
    $tab = $line[0];
    mysql_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $DB_DST_NAME.$tab") or die('Couldn\'t drop table:'.mysql_error());
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $DB_DST_NAME.$tab LIKE $DB_SRC_NAME.$tab") or die(mysql_error()) or die('Couldn\'t create table:'.mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $DB_DST_NAME.$tab SELECT * FROM $DB_SRC_NAME.$tab") or die('Couldn\'t insert data:'.mysql_error());
    echo "Table: <b>" . $line[0] . " </b>Done<br>";
}
```

I tried to avoid exec, since some hosts do not allow it...

Comment: Thanks, had a need for this today and it worked like a charm.